# Group Grid entries by custom field

Tags: matrix, playa, relationships, grid

I have a grid field like this:

File - Text field - Relationship field

Where the file is a document, the text field is the title and the relationship field is the argument.

I would like to output the list of files like this:

Argument 1

- File 1
- File 2
- File 3

Argument 2

- File 4
- File 5
- File 6

And so on, therefore grouped by the relationship field.

Now I have something like

```
{grid}

<li><a href="{grid:file}"> {grid:text_field} </a> - {grid:relationship}{grid:relationship:title}{/grid:relationship}</li>

{/grid}
```

That shows me:

- File 1 - Argument 1
- File 2 - Argument 1
- File 3 - Argument 1
- File 4 - Argument 2
- File 5 - Argument 2
- File 6 - Argument 2

How can I output the items by grouping them by argument? It means that the relationship field must shows only one time per type, and create a list for every type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved using Matrix and Playa. I used those because of the Playa parents tag. I could not use the native features of Grid and Relationship because, according to the documentation, “Currently it is not possible to get the parents of a relationship field that is inside of a Grid field”.

The code is:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="arguments"}
 {title}
  {exp:playa:parents channel="documents" var_prefix="doc"}
   {doc:matrix_field search:relationship="[{entry_id}]"}
    <li><a href="{file}">{text_field}</a></li>
   {/doc:matrix_field}
  {/exp:playa:parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm just thinking here, but if you install [Stash](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash) and use something like the following. This code is not tested and not sure get_list can be nested but the theory should be sound :)

```
{exp:channel:entries url_title="{segment_2}"}
{exp:stash:set_list name="entries" parse_tags="yes"} //Grab all your entries
    {grid}
        {stash:title}{grid:text_field}{/stash:title}
        {stash:file}{grid:file}{/stash:file}
        {stash:related}{grid:relationship}{grid:relationship:title}{/grid:relationship}{/stash:related}
    {/grid}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:set_list name="group_titles" unique="yes" trim="yes"} //Grab just the titles in a seperate list
    {grid}
        {stash:group}{grid:relationship}{grid:relationship:title}{/grid:relationship}{/stash:group}
    {/grid}
{/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:channel:entries}

{exp:stash:parse}
{exp:stash:get_list name="group_titles" prefix="outer"} //Grab the list of titles
    <h1>{outer:group}</h1>
    {exp:stash:get_list name="entries" match="#{outer:group}#" against="related" prefix="inner"} //Grab the entries and match them against the current group
    <li>{inner:title} / {inner:file} / {inner:group}</li>
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar thing with matrix field and in a low variables field. Thanks to @stuartmcd69 - I simplified his a bit.

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="groups" parse_tags="yes" unique="yes" }
  {exp:low_variables:parse var="report_downloads" order_by="category"}
    {stash:group}{category}{/stash:group}
  {/exp:low_variables:parse}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

then further in the template the output

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="groups" unique="yes" trim="yes"}
  {exp:stash:embed name="downloads" stash:category="{group}"}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

and the embed template looks like

```
<h2>{stash:category}</h2>
<ul>
{exp:low_variables:parse var="report_downloads" search:category="={stash:category}"}
  <li>
    <a href="{file}">{title}</a>
  </li>
{/exp:low_variables:parse}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stephen T actually had a wonderful answer, maybe you try this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="zones"}
    <h4>{title}</h4>
    {parents field="zone_relationship_field" channel="club_listing"}
        {parents:title}<br>
    {/parents}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

See this link [Grouping entries by relationship field (title)](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24768/grouping-entries-by-relationship-field-title)