# Grouping entries by custom field

Tags: custom-fields, grouping

I was seeing this wunderful idea from Stephen T ([Grouping entries by relationship field (title)](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24768/grouping-entries-by-relationship-field-title)), unfortunately it's not working for me.

I have a channel called market which actually is a store where people can share reviews of their market visits. I would like to group by market visit. So it would look like this

July 30th

- Market A
- Market B

July 31st

- Market B
- Market C

As the date refers to the actual visit date and NOT the entry date, date_heading is not working (as it refers to enry date only)

Any idea is highly appreciated, especially a non thrid-party solution

Comment: Could you provide a little more details? Is the visit date obtained by the review entry (and is this done via comments or Channel Form)?

Comment: Appreciate your help, Nutmeg. I have postzed the solution below in case someone needs it too

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I feel like I am too stupid to read. Of course if works as described in the docs. Thanks Nutmeg for your help anyway. The visit date is obtained by a channel form and the code would look like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="market_visits" limit="10" orderby="visit date" sort="desc"}

       {date_heading display="daily"}
...
                  {visit date format="%d.%m.%Y"}
...
       {/date_heading}
...
                 <li>{market}</li>
    ...
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```